# Using += operator on a string in order to add .txt for file output

Tags: c++

I'm currently taking the first CompSci class in college and one of my assignments wants me to take a name as input, then use that name in order to make a file with that same name, but with ".txt" at the end.

It prints out what it should be named as, but I can't find any file under the name I tried inputting.

Does anyone know what went wrong?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string des_name;
    string ship_name;
    float ship_mass;
    float e_thrust;

    const float g0 = 9.8;

    cout << "Designer name: " << endl;
    getline(cin , des_name);

    cout << "Ship Name: " << endl;
    cin >> ship_name;
    ship_name += ".txt";

    cout << "Ship Mass: " << endl;
    cin >> ship_mass;

    cout << "Engine Thrust: " << endl;
    cin >> e_thrust;

    cout << "File written for " << ship_name;

    ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open(des_name.c_str());
    output_file << "##########" << ship_name << "##########" << endl << endl;
    output_file << "Designed by: " << setw(10) << des_name;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... you say CS or C-Sharp but this is C/C++ we see???

Comment: Please don't modify your question to incorporate the solution, it rather defeats the Q&A purpose of SO, meaning correct answers no longer make sense. Have rolled back the change.

Comment: @Top-Master: to be fair, it's the educational institutions that call it things like CS101 (CompSci, year 1, semester 1, I gather). I've changed it to CompSci to make it clearer. I'm still trying to decode your `rn` however :-)

Comment: That stands for right-now (in few posts I saw at least)

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, you open a file based on `des_name`, yet it's `ship_name` that you appended `.txt` to:

```
ship_name += ".txt";
:
output_file.open(des_name.c_str());
```

I'd be looking at *that* anomaly as a starting point :-)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I feel really stupid now though. I saw this error earlier and somehow thought I fixed it when really I hadn't replaced the correct string to name the file as.